# How to get this cookie to expire after 14 days

Tags: javascript, cookies

```js
function setcookie(cookieName, cookieValue, nDays) {
  var today = new Date();
  var expire = new Date();
  if (nDays == null || nDays == 0) nDays = 1;
  expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * nDays); // changed that to * 14
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue) + ";expires=" + expire.toGMTString();
}

function readcookie(cookieName) {
  var theCookie = " " + document.cookie;
  var ind = theCookie.indexOf(" " + cookieName + "=");
  if (ind == -1) ind = theCookie.indexOf(";" + cookieName + "=");
  if (ind == -1 || cookieName == "") return "";
  var ind1 = theCookie.indexOf(";", ind + 1);
  if (ind1 == -1) ind1 = theCookie.length;
  return unescape(theCookie.substring(ind + cookieName.length + 2, ind1));

}
```

I tried changing `nday` to `nday=14` but nothing.

Then I tried `expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000 * 24 * 14)` , 
still nothing

I just need to use this code to get the cookie to expire after a set number of days.  Sorry i am new to javascript just started this week.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you always want to set your cookies for 14 days, delete your nDays parameter and set 14 days directly in the expire.setTime method

```
function setcookie(cookieName,cookieValue) {
    var today = new Date();
    var expire = new Date();
    expire.setTime(today.getTime() + 3600000*24*14);
    document.cookie = cookieName+"="+encodeURI(cookieValue) + ";expires="+expire.toGMTString();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that out. Can I ask though how come when I changed nDays=14; It did not work. I assumed it would do 360000 * 24 * nDays which would have been 14.

Comment: Delete "if (nDays == null || nDays == 0)" line and it will be ok

Comment: Why create the date first and then mutate it? Why not directly `new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 3600 * 24 * numDays)`?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use milliseconds you can also use this function:

```
function AddDays (days) {
    var today = new Date();
    var resultDate = new Date(today);
    resultDate.setDate(today.getDate()+days);
    return resultDate;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the lazy:

```
document.cookie = "your_cookie_name=your_cookie_value; max-age=1209600; path=/";
```